# Como tirar o índice da variável em python

Tags: python, pandas, índices

Aqui está um trecho do meu código. Basicamente ele lê um excel e retira de cada coluna as informações que eu preciso. Quando eu peço pra ele pegar a primeira variável, que é o nome no caso, ele aparece um índice do lado do nome, no caso um 0, já puis o reset_index mas mesmo assim não funcionou. Alguém pode me dar um conselho?

```
python
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Augusto\Desktop\Planilha de Vendas.xlsx')
i = list(range(1,11))
p = 0
q = 2
for j in i:
    x.reset_index()
    a = x.iloc[p:q]
    p = p + 3
    q = q + 3
    nomeF = a.iloc[:1, 1] # Nome do Formando
    print(nomeF)
```

Console:
0    Exemplo da Silva
Name: Nome*, dtype: object

Answer (score 0):

## Você pode usar fatiamento (slicing) para obter uma substring do que você precisa; ficaria assim:

```
x = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Augusto\Desktop\Planilha de Vendas.xlsx')
i = list(range(1,11))
p = 0
q = 2
for j in i:
    x.reset_index()
    a = x.iloc[p:q]
    p = p + 3
    q = q + 3
    nomeF = str(a.iloc[:1, 1])
```

## Caso queira cortar o zero do início:

```
    print(nomeF[1:])
```

## Caso queira cortar algo do final:

```
    print(texto[1:-1])
```

Espero ter ajudado.